# Como procurar um dispositivo em uma rede interna usando Javascript e/ou Node js

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, websocket

Estou criando uma aplicação que usa Websocket para conectar dois dispositivos em uma rede interna, porém para que isso seja feito, é necessário que o usuário digite o endereço do servidor Node js em uma campo de texto para que o mesmo seja utilizado para criar uma conexão Websocket entre a aplicação HTML5 e o Servidor Node js.

Mas caso fosse possível, gostaria de eliminar a necessidade de se digitar o endereço para criar esta conexão, pensei ser impossível a princípio, na verdade nem considerei isto a princípio até ter contato com a aplicação Keynote da Apple, nesta aplicação é possível conectar dois dispositivos na mesma rede para assim poder controlar a apresentação de slides com seu iPad enquanto seu Mac projeta a apresentação, por exemplo.

No Keynote, para criar esta conexão é necessário apenas que os dois dispositivos estejam conectados na mesma rede e utilizando o mesmo aplicativo ao mesmo tempo, sem a necessidade de se digitar IP algum, isto me deixou intrigado e me deu alguma esperança de que o mesmo possa ser feito com Javascript e Node js. Sei que eles possivelmente se utilizam de alguma tecnologia ou padrão ao qual não tenho acesso, mas gostaria de pelo menos saber como isto foi feito. Teorias que possam funcionar teoricamente também são bem vindas.

Comment: Se não houver resposta em dois dias, vou colocar uma recompensa aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Em Node JS, não deve ser tão difícil; se a ideia é simplesmente eliminar a necessidade de o usuário lidar com números de IP, basta então que haja um servidor Node JS que centralize os acessos e devolva aos usuários os números de IP recentemente conectados. Obviamente, isso exige um computador servidor na rede (DENTRO dela), e cada cliente ainda teria que conhecer um único número de IP indispensável: o desta máquina central.

Já em JavaScript, as coisas não são assim tão certas. O JS sofre com severas restrições, principalmente por motivos de segurança, mas já se discute uma [API para descoberta de rede](http://www.w3.org/TR/discovery-api/). Até que algo palpável surja dali, recomendo que você dê uma olhada no projeto [mdns-browser](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/mdns-browser) para ver o que pode ser aproveitado em um projeto web simples, ou o que você poderia mudar no seu projeto para conseguir tirar proveito das funcionalidades do Chrome.

Comment: Quuanto ao servidor node na rede e precisar saber o IP dele: acho que cada cliente pode fazer um *broadcast* ao ser inicializado, perguntando se há servidor ativo. O servidor, ao captar a requisição, pode mandar uma resposta direta ao cliente informando seu IP. Isso elimina a necessidade de se conhecer o IP do servidor de antemão.

Comment: Então, @Renan, pelo que sei, a dificuldade reside justamente em **fazer** um broadcast; mas se existe uma maneira de desempenhar esta tarefa diretamente no client, então realmente dá para implementar a melhoria que você disse - ou então partir direto para a descoberta automática dos *demais* clients, como originalmente planejado.

Comment: entendo, não tinha pensado nisso. Alternativamente o servidor pode fazer um broadcast a cada 'n' segundos, acho que isso fica mais fácil.

Comment: Super certo. Eu tinha na cabeça que era um serviço no estilo "chat", em que só participa quem tinha intenção de participar; pode não ser o caso. Dessa maneira, podemos sim tirar proveito da habilidade do *servidor* para criar broadcasts em um intervalo regular de tempo, ou ainda sob demanda do cliente. Assim, os clients JS rodando o aplicativo poderiam responder 'passivamente' os broadcasts para confirmar  que estão aptos a receber mensagens via socket provenientes dos demais hosts.

Comment: Acho que entendi sua proposta, o problema é que eu gostaria de poder lidar com possibilidades na qual não se sabe o IP do servidor de modo que qualquer pessoa consiga usar em sua rede interna apenas rodando o server NodeJS. O que eu quero construir (e que talvez eu devesse ter dito desde o início) seria uma aplicação para se exibir slides construídos em HTML5 e que pudessem ser controlados a distancia como no Keynote citado lá em cima. vou pesquisar melhor sobre a API para descoberta de rede e talvez se houvesse como garantir um IP interno através do próprio nodeJS exclusivo para este fim...

Answer (score 0):

A descoberta automática de serviços na rede que você experimentou no Keynote é provavelmente implementada pelo [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html) (mDNS). É um projeto open-source da Apple e tem add-ons em várias linguagens. Para Node.js você vai encontrar em [node_mdns](https://github.com/agnat/node_mdns): `npm install mdns`.